# How to trace the origin of a powershell script in azure

Tags: powershell, azure, scripting, trace

I'm going through a hard situation. Since we are alot of people working over the same subscription, and we are all admins, we all are launching scripts to azure.

The problem is that I have a data base wich is being duplicated automatically every day. When I go to the log I only can find that it's been clonated at certain hour, but the origin logs like:

```
{
    "relatedEvents": [],
    "authorization": null,
    "caller": null,
    "category": {
        "localizedValue": "Administrative",
        "value": "Administrative"
    }
}
```

And there is no place where I can find the origin or the user who has launch such script.

Is there any way to know that or to use any tool to trace the origin ?

It could have been launched from a scheduled task from inside azure, but we have searched into any of our IaaS and we cannot find anything.

Comment: I would suggest checking Audit Logs in the portal. You should be able to find information there.

Comment: I have already seen them and they have the same unproductive content. It's like when you are already logged you don't leave any trace